# How can you search a sharepoint library using Windows 7 Search Federation?

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint, search

I'd like to create a custom search provider for a sharepoint document library on Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Create a Windows 7 Federated Search provider for SharePoint](http://www.wssdemo.com/Blog/archive/2009/01/12/Create-a-Windows-7-Federated-Search-provider-for-SharePoint.aspx) by Ian Morrish. This describes the OSDX file you need to create.

Answer (score 0):

In case the referenced blog post dissapears, the markup looks like this:

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
> <OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:ms-ose="http://schemas.microsoft.com/opensearchext/2009/"> 
> <ShortName>WSSDemo Site</ShortName> 
> <Description>Search the Ian Morrish Sharepoint Demo site.</Description> 
> <Url type="application/rss+xml" template="http://www.wssdemo.com/search/_layouts/srchrss.aspx?k={searchTerms}&amp;start={startIndex}&amp;s=WSSDemo%20Content"/> 
> <Url type="text/html" template="http://www.wssdemo.com/search/Pages/Results.aspx?k={searchTerms}&amp;s=WSSDemo%20Content"/> 
> <!-- Win7 M3 syntax --> 
> <ms-ose:locationProperties> 
> <ms-ose:property name="TreatLinkAsEnclosure">-1</ms-ose:property> 
> </ms-ose:locationProperties> 
> <!-- Win7 Beta syntax --> 
> <ms-ose:ResultsProcessing format="application/rss+xml"> 
> <ms-ose:LinkIsFilePath>-1</ms-ose:LinkIsFilePath> 
> </ms-ose:ResultsProcessing> 
> </OpenSearchDescription>

Comment: :D "Buy this domain"